# Which hop is the correct 'next-hop' to use when Paris-Traceroute returns multiple next-hops?

Tags: traceroute

I'm using M-Lab and BigQuery, so I am dealing with previously collected data.  A large portion of the traceroutes I have include one or more diamonds, which usually have cycles. Is there a standard way to clean Paris-Traceroute data?  I was thinking of taking the shortest path.  In that case there are multiple shortest paths (diamonds that have multiple possible intermediate nodes give this), and I'm not sure which of the intermediate nodes is the best / most likely candidate.  I could choose the node the responded first?  I could choose the node that appears most often in routes from the source to destination (if one does)?